# Download entire folder from server using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking

I have an application that downloads a dozen HTML files one by one to the cache directory. But I now need to download all contents on a folder from my server to the cache directory, they will all be images.

I don't know if it is a different approach, I can probably accomplish it by specifying each filename but I don't want to have to do that.

I am using AFNetworking, any direction would be great!

Comment: You can zip the folder and upzip it after finished downloading.

Comment: Can you go into more details with the methods to use?

Comment: using zip file is good idea. so download only one file and unzip it after download complete.